# "Deviates from the original intent of the post" for grammar cleanup

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

The edit suggestion is linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23020265). If possible, I'd like to contest this rejection.

As mentioned in my summary I suggested minor grammar improvements, in addition to some punctuation/capitalization cleanup. The author of the question rejected it for deviating from the original intent of the post. I don't believe I crossed that line in my suggestion. Am I missing something?

Comment: The poster rejected it.  There's nothing to contest.

Comment: @fbueckert It is my belief that the author rejected it because they weren't open to any edits at all, rather than them actually believing my edits changed the intent of the post. So I do think there are grounds for contesting.

Comment: The original poster has the final say on edits to their question. Just move on.

Comment: @greg-449 actually, no, they don't. If they are deliberately making the post *worse*, we can impose the better version of the post..

Comment: Your edits here were correct and useful. They were wrongly rejected. It happens sometimes; please do not be discouraged. Thank you for your assistance in improving the site one post at a time!

Comment: @greg-449: only up to a point. The edit was overwhelmingly good, and that needs to override the author (especially if they don't know about our editing culture, as is likely in this case).

Comment: I personally never understood of edits and I always feel a pang when someone edits my posts for anything more than trivial typo. My post is my statement, and this is what I wanted to say. When someone alters my words, it doesn't feel right. I always welcome comments, but it should be my decision. If you feel answer is not great or inaccurate, you might as well post your own.

Comment: @SergeyA Yeah, there's definitely a pang. But part of my motivation for editing questions is to improve their clarity; even if I can't answer something, maybe I can make it easier for someone else to. I like to think of it as just changing some variable names in a piece of code to make it more self-documenting. I do my best not to change their overall writing style; it's one of the reasons I don't really do answer edits.

I like to think of all the content on here as community-owned. If we can help make something better for the next person to find, we should.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your edit was an improvement, so you have that part correct, at least (and thank you for trying to improve posts that need it). What you're missing is that OP rejected the edit, which is their purview–as OP, they have unilateral ability to reject suggested edits, even after they've been approved by other users. This is despite the fact OP chose a rejection reason that clearly does not apply.

In this case, as someone who does not have full edit capabilities, the best option is to accept that OP doesn't want their question improved, downvote it for being low quality/refusing improvements if you like, and move on.

Comment: Moderators also have unilateral ability to approve/reject suggested edits, even after they’ve been approved/rejected by other users. This is one of the cases where I would have used that ability, had I seen it before Braiam edited. (An intervening edit prevents us from using this feature.) Although this doesn’t scale well, I think this was an exceptional case. Furthermore, it is just as likely that the OP misunderstood how collaborative editing works, rather than preferring their question to be ungrammatical. I can’t tell you how many rollback wars OPs have with themselves.